# How to Split the Predicted Probabilities Produced by ML Pileline Logistic Regression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to extract the predicted probability from the logistic model using ML pipeline and DataFrame API. The output of predicted probabilities is a column vector that stores the predicted probabilities for each class(0, 1) in as shown below. I wonder how I can extract only the probability for class 1. Thank you!

> prob
>   "[0.13293408418007766,0.8670659158199223]"
>   "[0.1335112097146626,0.8664887902853374]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UDF like this should work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val getPOne = udf((v: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) => v(1))
model.transform(testDf).select(getPOne($"probability"))
```

Answer (score 0):

such way can also reach the goal.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
model.transform(dataDF).select("prob").map(row => row.getAs[Vector]("prob").toArray)
```

then you can get what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also first case the probability column to org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector, and then extract the element.

```
model.transform(testDf).select("probability").map(e=> e.asInstanceOf[DenseVector]).map(e=> e(1))
```